# React native play sound on togglebutton

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio

I just started to react native and  got a flatlist with multitext, the text changes on click

You can try it, it well works

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground
} from 'react-native';
const ToggleButton = (props) => {
  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
  const { sample, id, onPress, item1, item2 } = props;
  const text = isPressed ? item2.sample2 : item1.sample;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setIsPressed(!isPressed);
        onPress && onPress();
      }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: '100%',
          height: 129,
          backgroundColor:'#E7C287',
          borderWidth: 1,
          marginTop:36,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding:8
        }}>
        <Text style={{   fontSize: 14 }}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  
};

const Myappp = () => {
  const data = [
    {sample:"My list1",id:"1"},
{sample:"My list2",id:"2"},
{sample:"My list3",id:"3"}, ];
  const data2 = [
    {sample2:"My changed list1",id:"1"},
    {sample2:"My changed list2",id:"2"},
    {sample2:"My changed list3",id:"3"}, ];
    
  

  return (
    
      <Text style={{marginTop:21,
    padding:16,
    marginBottom:27,
    fontSize:28,
    alignItems: 'center', 
    }}>My first try</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={(entry) => {
          const { item } = entry;
          return (
            <ToggleButton
              item1={item}
              item2={data2.filter((_item) => _item.id === item.id)[0]}
            />
          );
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 20 }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
          return <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 10 }} />;
        }}
        keyExtractor={(entry, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    
  );
  
};

export default Myappp;
```

I just want add some touch sound, it will play(like 2 sec) then stop.There will be 5-10 mp3 in the "sound" folder.

I searched for playing song and I found this but I don't know how to merge it. Can anybody help me please.
Thank you

```
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

const sound = new Sound('http://sounds.com/some-sound', null, (error) => {
                        //for my app , like ("./sounds/aaaa.mp3")
  if (error) {
    // do something
  }
  
  // play when loaded
  sound.play();
});
```

There is also expo-av package but I don't think it will work when I generate apk file from android studio

```
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

try {
  const { sound: soundObject, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
    require('./assets/sounds/hello.mp3'),
    { shouldPlay: true }
  );
  // Your sound is playing!
} catch (error) {
  // An error occurred!
}
```

How can I make it